# input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have been using Ubuntu since Christmas, and just recently I have been receiving delayed input while using the Ubuntu terminal.  It especially takes affect when using vim or man commands, which is strange as no other software I have has no delay when typing even UTerm and UXTerm have no delay.

**What I have tried**:

- restarting pc
- updating drivers
- changed keyboard input

**System Info**:

- OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Gnome version: 42.9
- Windowing system: X11

if any extra details are needed please ask.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/8070 looks like another report of probably the same issue. No report about lagging for years, and then suddenly 4 different people report it in just a bit over 24 hours. Must be some recent Ubuntu update that broke something. They did not update their VTE or GNOME Terminal packages recently, so it must be an update to an underlying package that is either buggy, or happens to trigger a bug in VTE / GNOME Terminal.

Comment: I have a hunch that the fix to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2054510 may be the culprit; in that case reverting the `[lib]mutter*` packages to 42.9-0ubuntu5 (22.04) / 45.2-0ubuntu3 (23.10) and restarting the graphical session should fix the issue. Since I cannot reproduce the issue, I cannot confirm this suspicion. It would be great if you could test it and provide feedback!

Comment: Looks like it's indeed caused by a `mutter` bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/3384