Bash terminal has become extremely slow. 22.04
My bash terminal has become extremely slow, I until 22.04. I don't have any extensions installed but I think it might be related to some form of auto complete/search.
Additionally gnome-shell has high memory usage, 5.4gb virtual 244mb active.
How do I find the problem?

Possibly this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1509058/380067

I'm trying that fix

That seemed to have fixed it

Glad it did, I'll close this question as a duplicate of the question I linked then.

Recently I enabled the dconf setting org/gnome/wayland/xwayland-allow-grabs. This fixed an issue where whenever I tried to use ctrl+alt+t (or any shortcut that used an alphanumeric) to open the terminal the desktop would then be searched for the letter "t"; however, enabling this setting also seems to have improved responsiveness system wide.
Likely not the culprit, but since both of these issues seem to involve mutter (as per kos's comment above) and sluggish inputs, I thought I would comment just in case it actually does help.
Cheers.

Not an answer to the question, but would you mind posting a Q/A on this? There should be a question / answer to this bug, despite not having even experienced it I'm by osmosis feeling annoyed by it myself...

How do I change settings?

@FourierFlux To change the settings I commented about, you have to install the dconf Editor and navigate to that address.

@kos posted the Q/A

@J.Tho Thanks!!
