Terminal skips the last redraw sometimes
I started to notice lately that my Ubuntu 22.04.3 Gnome terminal feels kinda laggy. If I pay attention, it turns out that sometimes terminal is one redraw behind when I type. E.g. if I type in "bin" the terminal will show only "bi" until another redraw operation is triggered (for example, by pressing left, or printing another character). Then if I press "u" the terminal shows "bin", and "u" waits for the next key press.
This also happens with more complex operations. For example, pressing enter to run a command that does not print anything usually shows a new line for a new command, but in my case the new line will appear only when I start typing.
Important to note, it doesn't happen 100% of times, and usually doesn't happen in freshly open terminal window, only after a few commands are executed.
What I've tried to fix it:

Installed all updates - no effect
Checked if it is related to CPU overheating and throttling (since it only happens after I run something). CPU temperature doesn't have any effect.
Checked if it is related to GPU being used - changed NVidia settings from Balance to Performance and back - no effect
Tried terminator, xterm and Idea terminal emulators instead of Gnome one. All work the same (with same lags).
Tried terminal without X11 (Alt+Ctrl+F3) - super-responsive, I will probably have to work there until I find solution for this issue
Tried terminal-like applications (neovide - GUI for neovim), no lags there

I'm completely lost and have no idea where to look for solution for this, but I really need one, as it becomes at times completely unbearable to work in the terminal like this. I feel it must be related to X11 and how it communicates with windows (since native terminal works fine), but don't know how to dig for that...

First thing to do is sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade you are way behind in updates. See if you still have an issue after. You should be showing Ubuntu 22.04.4

fyi:   as already stated by @DavidDE; https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded before that date, so your details (if accurate) imply you've not been applying security fixes & other upgrades since before that date; OR 22.04.3 is a symptom of this or another problem.

Please, create a new Linux user and try from that user. If the problem is not present there, then there is something wrong with the GNOME configuration of your user.

Sounds like a video driver issue. Probably something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509058/input-delay-on-terminal-ubuntu-22-04-4/1509271

Thanks for the pointers, @David DE and @guiverc. It turns out that I was subscribed only to security updates, so upgrading everything didn't actually install all the new updates. After changing the subscription to all updates, the system upgraded to 22.04.4, which included updates to Gnome and Nvidia drivers. I also had to restart the system after the update. And one of those three has fixed the issue. The terminal works fine now, so I'll mark this question as answered (even though, I don't know what caused the issue in the first place).
